# Applying for a different PhD, should I say I am already in one?

Tags: phd, application

I am considering on applying for a different PhD position in a different university and even different country, but I don't know if I should mention I am already in one, and I'm planning to leave it, or just address that as a research assistant position, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

When applying for a job, be honest. Just assume that people will find out eventually, because most of the time they will. Say you got accepted, and your new advisor happens to talk to your old advisor on a conference. Now (s)he has the impression that you were dishonest. That is bad.